# JAX-WS client with AXIS server; missing namespace in response

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, axis

I'm having a problem related to JAX-WS and AXIS. JAX-WS (2.1.7) as a client, Axis (1.4.x) as server.

Everything works OK, but the response can't be read to Java.

Response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
  <ns1:myserviceResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://my/service">
   <ns1:myserviceReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">responsestring</ns1:myserviceReturn>
  </ns1:myserviceResponse>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The problem is that if `ns1:`-namespace declaration is removed from `myserviceReturn`, JAX-WS is able to return anything else than null.

Does anyone have a clue how to force JAX-WS to ignore namespaces, how to modify SOAP response manually to exclude "ns1", or other ideas for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a custom WSDL file that does not include the name space.  This file goes in the META-INF directory.  You can start with the default one that your app has now, then save it here.